# How to trace spoofed phone numbers?

Tags: spoofing

I keep getting scam calls using spoofed phone numbers.

Is there a way for me to trace? I have contacted the authorities but they seem to be not as enthusiastic as I am about solving the issue.

Comment: Which authorities? I don't know about your situation, but I am under the impression jurisdiction is usually a big issue with scam calls.

Comment: I am based in singapore and the scam callers claim to be based in Switzerland. The spoofed numbers are Singapore numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, all I can say to that is I know nothing about Singapore jurisdiction, apart from the fact that there are certainly people somewhere who do know something about it.